# Merge coordinate into existing line

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp, geosphere

I want to merge additional spatial coordinates into a preexisting spatial line.

**My data:**

1. Spatial coordinates representing coastlines.
2. Spatial coordinates representing observations.

Observations do not necessarily match coordinates on the lines, so I have snapped the observations to the lines. This gives a new coordinate for the observation: its place on the preexisting  line.

I want to merge this new coordinate into the original spatial lines data, in the correct place so it does not disrupt the correct order of original coordinates along the line.

I have looked into the `sp` object manipulations, but cannot figure out how to produce the data structure I am after.

```r
# Pre-existing line
> head(grpCoords)
         LONG       LAT
[1,] 140.6615 -8.846777
[2,] 140.5811 -8.728320
[3,] 140.4897 -8.620410
[4,] 140.1017 -8.300586
[5,] 140.0029 -8.195508
[6,] 139.9833 -8.166504

# Observation
> xy
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  167  -45

# New coordinate for observation on the line
> dist2Line(xy, grpCoords)
     distance      lon       lat
[1,]  4123324 150.4824 -10.63691
```

For example: For XY coordinates representing the line:

```
XY[1,1] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ XY[1,9] _ _ XY[1,12]
```

Where:

```r
LONG LAT
1    1
1    9
1    12
```

If the observed coordinate is XY[1,8],  I would expect:

```
XY[1,1] _ _ _ _ _ _ XY[1,8] XY[1,9] _ _ XY[1,12]
```

And the merged data to be:

```r
LONG LAT
1    1
1    8
1    9
1    12
```

Comment: Hi, could you please [make this more reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) and on-topic for Stack Overflow with it?

Comment: I would look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/270814/32531 to turn your points into a line instead of "merging"